# Отправкой данных из формы на API

Tags: php, api

подскажите пожалуйста решение, или хотя бы куда смотреть по следующему вопросу: Есть форма

```
    <form data-name="Email Form" name="email-form" action="https://window.sv-house.com/..\..\#" class="members-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="firstname form-control w-input valid" maxlength="256" name="FunnelRegistrationForm[first_name]" data-name="FunnelRegistrationForm[first_name]" placeholder="First Name" aria-invalid="false">
<div class="warning-icon"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control w-input valid" maxlength="256" name="FunnelRegistrationForm[last_name]" data-name="FunnelRegistrationForm[last_name]" placeholder="Last Name" aria-invalid="false">
<div class="warning-icon"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"><input type="email" class="form-control w-input valid" maxlength="256" name="FunnelRegistrationForm[email]" data-name="FunnelRegistrationForm[email]" placeholder="E-mail" aria-invalid="false">
<div class="warning-icon"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-row-nowrap">
<div class="form-cell form-cell-1">
<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control w-input valid" maxlength="256" name="FunnelRegistrationForm[password]" data-name="FunnelRegistrationForm[password]" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{6,12}$" placeholder="Password">
<div class="warning-icon"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-cell form-cell-2">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="nice-btn generate-pass">Generate passwords</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control w-input valid" maxlength="256" name="FunnelRegistrationForm[country]" data-name="FunnelRegistrationForm[country]" placeholder="Country" aria-invalid="false" data-value="UA" readonly="">
<div class="warning-icon"></div>
</div>
<div class="phone-row">
<div class="prefix-cell">
<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control w-input valid" maxlength="256" name="FunnelRegistrationForm[phone_prefix]" data-name="FunnelRegistrationForm[phone_prefix]" placeholder="Prefix" aria-invalid="false" readonly="">
<div class="warning-icon"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="phone-cell">
<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control w-input valid" maxlength="256" name="FunnelRegistrationForm[phone_number]" data-name="FunnelRegistrationForm[phone_number]" placeholder="Phone" aria-invalid="false"><label id="FunnelRegistrationForm[phone_number]-error" class="error" for="FunnelRegistrationForm[phone_number]" style="display: none;"></label>
<div class="warning-icon"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div><input type="submit" value="GET STARTED NOW !" data-wait="Please wait..." class="nice-btn btn-submit w-button">
<div class="scenario-input w-embed"><input type="hidden" name="scenario" value="_user_registration_without_phone"></div>
</form>
```

каким образом реализуется отправка данных из формы на АПИ? Как их прислать на почту это не проблема но появилась необходимость отправлять на АПИ, с гугла я только понял что ето не проблема но каких-то конкретных примеров,  вот так так собираем данные, так идет пхп файл, отправляем, так получаем ответ не нашел. Спасибо заранее за ответ у кого есть возможность подсказать

Comment: Скажите, Денис. А вы понимаете, что на почту отправляете данные не "из формы", а из программы на РНР? Что сначала вы отправляете форму в РНР, а потом уже РНР куда-то отправляет неважно откуда полученные данные?

Comment: Здравствуйте, ну да, мы же в экшене указываем файл пхп который уже соберет данные из формы и через сендмейл отправит на почтовый ящик который там уже задуман

Comment: правильно. А это значит что ваш вопрос не "как отправить форму на апи", а "как из РНР отправить данные на апи". И на этот вопрос есть примерно миллион готовых ответов.

Comment: спасибо, как я понял принцип примерно тот же, только в данном случае лучше аяксом: сначала написать тип запроса, далее получаем строку данных из формы пригодную для передачи в ссылке, и дальше все это отдаем на пхп файл. Я как набрасаю пример я могу тут же же уточнить?

Comment: при чем здесь аякс вообще? Вы можете определиться, вам из формы надо отправлять на апи, или из РНР? В РНР нет никаких аяксов. Вы можете не метаться туда-сюда, и определиться наконец, что вам надо сделать - данные отправить или с аяксом поиграться?

Comment: в момент, когда вы отправляете данные на емейл, у вас уже **нет никаких форм и аяксов** у вас есть только **массив с данными**. Откуда он получен - из формы, или из носа выковырян - вообще никакого значения не имеет. поэтому вам надо собраться с мыслями и объяснить, на какое апи, зачем и откуда вы собрались что-то отправлять. Если так же как на почту, то никаких аяксов у вас тут уже нет.

Comment: Есть форма, данные нужно с нее направить в АПИ и получить ссылку уже на эти данные и перенаправить пользователя по этой ссылке, За аякс я подумал чтобы пользователя сразу не перебрасывало на пхп файл

Comment: Ну извините если Вас я взбесил своими вопросами, просто впервые столкнулса именно с такой задачей поетому и тупые вопросы немного

Comment: вы вообще помните, о чем говорили 5 минут назад? Так откуда надо обращаться к апи? Если из формы, то при чем тут вообще РНР? Если из РНР, то при чем тут формы или аякс? Давайте оставим мою скромную персону в покое и вернётся к вашему вопросу. Который вам надо, собравшись с силами, наконец сформулировать

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо разобраться как работает веб. Я накидал диаграмму для вашего случая. Отправка на API изображена справа. Ваша программа (скрипт) на PHP делает HTTP-запрос к серверу API, передавая данные, полученные из $_POST.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

API это, грубо говоря, такой же сайт как и ваш, только он рассчитан на взаимодействие программ, а не людей. Для отправки данных вам надо сделать HTTP-запрос из PHP. Гуглите "php http request" и в таком духе.

API бывают разные ([JSON-RPC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC), [SOAP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)), иногда ваш запрос должен содержать довольно сложный документ. Для конкретного типа API можно найти специальные библиотеки, упрощающие взаимодействие. Если у вашего API простой интерфейс, то напишите свою реализацию, если там SOAP, то возьмите готовую библиотеку.